# Using different screen layouts

Tags: android, android-layout

I have an app with different versions for screens (small, normal, largue, and extraLargue XML files) each with its XML designed for each type, but I found a Huawei phone with this screen 3.5" HVGA 320x480.

My question is, should not the UI of Android use the small configuration for this screen? Is that the app when running on this phone uses the normal configuration as if it were a nexus4 4.7" 768x1280 as I change that?

I tried to create various types of screen (create other) with multiple configurations without optimal result.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the 3.5" measurement is on the diagonal, this works out to about 165 dpi which falls into the mdpi (or normal screen size) bucket according to Android's Supporting Multiple Screens guide.

```
DPI = sqrt(w^2 + h^2) / d

where 

w is the width of the display in pixels
h is the height of the display in pixels
d is the physical diagonal measurement of the display in inches
```

Answer (score -1):

It is quite simple.
You need to add different UI and make controls `VISIBILE` and `GONE`.

```
int appScreen = getResources().getConfiguration().screenLayout &
        Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK;


switch(appScreen) {
    case Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_LARGE:
    UIControl.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        break;
    case Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_NORMAL:
    UIControl.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        break;
    case Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_SMALL:
    UIControl.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        break;
    default:
    UIControl.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
```

Comment: Better yet just provide different XML layout files foot each configuration.

Comment: that makes sense too